# ace-editor setting new session

Tags: javascript, session, ace-editor

I am trying to implement tabs in an ace editor text area and want to be able to create new session when a new tab is made, and switch between them when changing tabs.

I'm stuck at being able to make a new session.

this is from the ace editor website

```
new EditSession(Document | String text, TextMode mode)
Sets up a new EditSession and associates it with the given Document and TextMode.
Arguments
text    Document | String   
Required. If text is a Document, it associates the EditSession with it. Otherwise, a           new Document is created, with the initial text
mode    TextMode    
Required. The inital language mode to use for the document
```

so to make a new session i have tried

```
session1 = new EditSession("some text", "javascript");
```

and i get the error message

```
ReferenceError: EditSession is not defined
```

i've also tried

```
this.setSession(session || new EditSession(""));

eg. editor.setSession(new EditSession("session1"));
```

which comes up with the same error message

Comment: There is a web app example of multiple sessions with tabs and "undo" and "redo" working by being managed by the `UndoManager` at GitHub repo: [https://github.com/Blueprinter/Ace-editor-multiple-sessions-tabbed](https://github.com/Blueprinter/Ace-editor-multiple-sessions-tabbed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ace creates only one global `ace`, everything else must be obtained either from require (if you use it) or from `ace.require`
In your example `ReferenceError: EditSession is not defined` means you do not have any variable named `EditSession`.

When using `session = new EditSession("editor content", string mode);`
to create an `EditSession` this way you need to add undomanager to it.

But there is `ace.createEditSession` [method](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ace.js#L125-L129), which creates a new session and sets up undoManager for it.

```
session = ace.createEditSession("string or array", "ace/mode/javascript")
```

note that for modes you need to use a path to the mode, like "ace/mode/...", not simply "javascript"

Comment: class keeping track of editing history. without it ctrl-z won't work

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here  :D

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ace-discuss/oL5uU_kebfE
```

because the packaged version of ace has a fallback function if RequireJS is not available I have to use ist this was:

```
EditSession = ace.require("ace/edit_session").EditSession;
var tester = new EditSession('');
```

though i still don't know why the function i was using originally wasn't working, probably something to do with require.js, of which i know nothing about, so i guess i haven't really answered my own question all that well yet.